# Draw QML overlay in a GStreamer plug-in?

Tags: qml, gstreamer

After some searching, I see there is machinery in place in Qt to play video from GStreamer backend in a QML application. But I am interested in quite the opposite: do you know if it is possible to render QML graphics, probably with animations, in a GStreamer plug-in (filter)? Ideally, I would like to be able to feed my QML to a GStreamer plug-in and have it rendered over the video. The rendered output would be piped for further processing down the GStreamer pipeline. What do you think?

Thanks a lot in advance!

--
Vlad

Comment: you can try compositor/glvideomixer for overlaying, and appsrc as source of qml graphics.. but you have to find a way to extract frames from QML..

Comment: @otopolsky: right, thanks, I was thinking something like that. Actually, I believe there are two ways: 1) gstreamer plugin with QML, and 2) gstreamer pipeline with appsrc and Qt application that draws QML and submits frames to the pipeline. I personally think 2nd approach might be easier to implement, but 1st is kind of cleaner -- the gstreamer way: you don't need to link your application with h.264 libraries in order to use it in the pipeline, do you?